# dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: can't resolve symbol ___cxa_guard_acquire

Tags: ios, swift, ocr, tesseract, dyld

I am trying to implement the OCR library Tesseract OCR, but everytime i try to run it, it show same error mentioned below. Pleas help if somebody has resolved this issue. I am attaching screenshot of error also.

```
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: can't resolve symbol ___cxa_guard_acquire in /Users/saurabhrana/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/20C04E36-8181-4935-B52E-5B5871911BDF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9D18AA35-8D47-4CDF-B593-2A8DF52B1550/TextRecognition.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR because dependent dylib #1 could not be loaded
dyld: can't resolve symbol ___cxa_guard_acquire in /Users/saurabhrana/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/20C04E36-8181-4935-B52E-5B5871911BDF/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/9D18AA35-8D47-4CDF-B593-2A8DF52B1550/TextRecognition.app/Frameworks/TesseractOCR.framework/TesseractOCR because dependent dylib #1 could not be loaded
```

See [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2igLG.png)